# Understanding which constructor is chosen and why

Tags: java

Why following program every time prints `I'm string` and not `I'm object.` or `I'm int.`?

```
public class Demo {

    public Demo(String s){
        System.out.println("I'm string");
    }

    public Demo(int i){
        System.out.println("I'm int.");
    }

    public Demo(Object o){
        System.out.println("I'm object.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo(null);
    }
}
```

Also if I replace `int` with `Integer`. It gives error as `The constructor Demo(String) is ambiguous.` Why?

Comment: Just to check, what happens if you change the order of the constructors. Put `Object` before `String`.

Comment: @Harry Weird... I don't know, then. Good luck!

Comment: @Oltarus -- change order of constructors? This is Java, not some scripting language. Method and constructor order does not matter (one exception is static & dynamic initialization blocks).

Comment: @Nick Sorry I upset you ;-) I didn't mean to insult this perfect language. I guess it was some kind of reflex, like the famous "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" that IT seems to love, whatever the problem is.

Comment: @Oltarus -- lol, no biggie, just someone had to point out the flaw in that approach w/ Java

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`null` can be converted to `Object` or `String`, but not `int`. Therefore the second constructor is out.

Between the conversion to `Object` or the conversion to `String`, the conversion to `String` is more specific, so that's what's picked.

The JLS [section 15.12.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#292575) describes method overload resolution, and I believe the same approach is used for constructor resolution. [Section 15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183) describes choosing the most specific method (constructor in this case):

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

This about the constructor invocation with Object or String arguments - any invocation handled by `new Demo(String)` could also be passed on to `new Demo(Object)` without a compile-time type error, but the reverse is *not* true, therefore the `new Demo(String)` one is more specific... and thus chosen by the overload resolution rules.

Comment: Great answer -- so that also explains why Demo(Integer) conflicts with Demo(String) when doing new Demo(null)

Comment: @Nick not even `Integer` but `Byte`, `BigDecimal` any `object` will be ambigous.

Comment: Thank you so much. Never known that this much happens when we call a method.

Comment: @JonSkeet : 'null' can be converted to 'Object' or 'String' , can this be explained a little more please

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri': It means that `Object x = null;` and `String y = null;` are both valid - basically the null reference is a valid value for a variable of *any* class type.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question (since Jon Skeet has already covered the first), when you have both a `String` constructor and an `Integer` constructor the compiler doesn't know what you mean by `null` in `new Demo(null)`: it could be either a `String` or an `Integer`.

Because `String` can't be cast to `Integer` (and vice versa) the compiler gives up and reports the ambiguous error. This is in contrast to the `String` vs `Object` choice when you don't have the `Integer` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you have constructors or methods like the above, the compiler generally tries to find the closest match possible and uses that.

The way to think of `null` in these circumstances is it acts as a subtype of all types (yes, it's not strictly speaking true but it provides a good platform for thinking about what happens). So using this rule it fits string more closely than object, hence this is the constructor that is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The fact the String constructor is mentioned in by the compiler in your second error:

```
The constructor Demo(String) is ambiguous.
```

is not significant.  This is because the Constructor which takes a String is the first declared constructor, so the compiler uses it in its error message.  Change to have the Object constructor first and you get:

```
The constructor Demo(Object) is ambiguous.
```

What it's trying to say is there's ambiguity between the constructor which takes the Integer and the Object, so you have to be more specific, as null can be applied to each.  Integer IS-NOT-A String, so the two types are not compatible.  You need to be more specific so the compiler can bind the constructor call.

See @Jon Skeet answer for why the compiler raises an error in some instances and not in others.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it may be because you imply that the constructor is chosen based on the order that they're declared in. This isn't the case, it's just the error message that uses this. You may want to clear up the wording so it's a bit clearer :)

Comment: yeah I can clear that up - I didn't mean that was the case, I was trying to state that the fact the compiler mentioned Demo(String) specifically wasn't significant.  I wish downvoters would add some comment ;)