# Java Overloaded Constructors

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding which constructor is chosen and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383632/help-in-understanding-java-program)

Why compiler acts like this,

```
public class  Calculator{

    private Calculator(Object o) {
        // code goes here
    }

    private Calculator(double[] calc) {
        // code goes here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Calculator(null);
    }
}
```

This program executes second constructor. Why first constructor not execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both constructors are accessible and applicable.

The constructor Calculator (Object) accepts any parameter passed to Calculator (double[]), so Calculator (Object) is less specific.